# How to get the client_id in the logout endpoint in OpenIddict?

Tags: asp.net, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm trying to get information about the client who initiated logout (like ClientId and display name).

But I can't get it from the request.

Here's is the LogOut action in the client application:

```
[Route("/logout")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult LogOut()
{
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/status"
    }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

From the HTTP request retrieved at the logout endpoint in OpenIddict server, the ClientId is null:

```
HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest().ClientId; // Null
```

but these parameters are sent: `post_logout_redirect_uri`, `id_token_hint`, `state` with the request.

Is there a way to include the ClientId with the logout request? In the specs (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout) it's optional, so maybe it can be enabled/disabled somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the OpenIddict client, that implements the latest draft of the RP-initiated logout specification and will send the `client_id` parameter for you. You can see it in action here: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Client

Alternatively, if you prefer using the MSFT OIDC handler, you can use its event model - and more specifically the [`OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onredirecttoidentityproviderforsignout?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-openidconnect-openidconnectevents-onredirecttoidentityproviderforsignout) event - to override the URL the user is redirected to when triggering a sign-out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm migrating from IdentityServer4 to OpenIddict, and I wish to not make changes to the clients. I can see in IS4, there is the method [`IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetLogoutContextAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/4dc10e665f5ede63274427036c25cdc216130eb9/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultIdentityServerInteractionService.cs#L68C42-L68C63) which returns the client's details. I'm not sure if it can be easily implemented in my OpenIddict server, but seems I'll need to store the login session (==big effort).

Comment: If the client send an `id_token_hint`, the claims contained in that identity token can be resolved from the logout endpoint by doing `var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`. If you need the identity of the client, you can resolve it via `result.Principal.GetAudiences().FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Very nice, now I have the `client_id`. One more question, is there a chance `GetAudience` could be null or doesn't hold the `client_id`?

Comment: In general it's not, but there are advanced scenarios where it can be null (e.g if you decide to return an identity token during a resource owner password credentials grant request as a non-standard extension mimicking OIDC).